# Prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**Question**

Suppose $f$ is $C^1([0,\infty))$, $f\geq 0$ and $f'\leq 1$ on $[0,\infty)$. If $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, show that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$.

---

Here is my attempt:
Suppose $f(x)\not\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. Then there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $M\in \mathbb R$, there exists $x>M$ such that $f(x)\geq \epsilon_0$. Take $M_1=1$, there exists $x_1>1$ such that $f(x)\geq \epsilon_0$ and therefore a $\delta_1>0$ such that $f(x)\geq \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}$ on $[x_1-\delta_1,x_1+\delta_1]$. Continue this process inductively by setting $M_{j+1}=x_j+\delta_j$. Then we have $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{x_n-\delta_n}^{x_n+\delta_n}f(x)dx\geq \epsilon_0\sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta_n.$$ However, I still need to show that $\sum \delta_n$ diverges.

Comment: There exists an $N$ such that $m,n> N \implies \int_n^m f(x)\ dx < \epsilon$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result known as Barbalats lemma, https://planetmath.org/barbualatslemma. In your case as $f \in C^1([0,\infty))$ with a bounded derivative it must be uniformly continuous, thus the lemma applies. Additionally here is a nice article discussing the lemma and different proofs, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1611.pdf.